# Formatting Yui Datatable caption

Tags: class, caption, yui-datatable

How can I add a class to the caption element of the Yui datatable apart from the default class i.e. "yui3-datatable-caption"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could change the [CAPTION_TEMPLATE](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.TableView.html#property_CAPTION_TEMPLATE) property.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning earlier my Yui version is 3.1

Comment: I'm afraid that is possibly an earlier version of DataTable that was deprecated long ago.  I doubt you will be able to find any support for that one.  A generic alternative to your problem is to enclose the text for your caption in a <span> tag with your desired className before setting it in the DataTable.